# How to monitor the amount of data traffic?

Tags: data-monitoring, resource-monitoring

I would like to monitor how much data-traffic I use. How?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is now built into Android in Ice Cream Sandwich. You can view usage per application, set limits and restrict background data.

Some more information: http://androidadvices.com/set-mobile-data-limit-usage-ice-cream-sandwich-devices/

[NetCounter](http://www.jaqpot.net/netcounter/) monitors mobile and wifi traffic.

Comment: Note that netcounter appears to be somewhat inaccurate

Comment: @AshtonBRSC: I think you should have added another answer, rather than radically changing this one.

Answer (score 3):

I use **[Data counter widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.roysolberg.android.datacounter&feature=search_result)**

And **[3G watchdog](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog)** to keep 3G traffic under control.

Comment: [3G Watchdog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.rgruet.android.g3watchdog) is another data monitor app; it has freely selectable time periods.

Answer (score 2):

Another option: [My Data Manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobidia.android.mdm)

[Lifehacker reviewed it](http://lifehacker.com/5822127/my-data-manager-monitors-and-manages-your-androids-data-plan):

> When installed it keeps track of your plan type (monthly or
>   pay-as-you-go), amount of data included per month, and the 1st day of
>   your billing cycle. You may also set your plan's roaming details. From
>   then on it will log your use of mobile data, roaming mobile data, and
>   Wi-Fi data used. You may setup notifications for each of the three
>   categories when they hit a certain amount of data.

Comment: I especially like the ability to set the billing-cycle start date.