# How can I manage/track the data use on a HTC Inspire?

Tags: data-monitoring, data-plan

I thought this would be a popular question but couldn't find it here so if you do please let me know.

My mother just got a new HTC Inspire and is brand new to using a data plan.  Since she is worried that she might go over her cap I want to know how can she track how much data she has used in a certain time (preferably within a billing period). I am on Sprint so I've never had to worry about how much data I use. My question is: **Can you recommend a method to manage/track data?**

Also, I figure that apps like weather and news should be changed to check less frequently... **any other *default apps* that should be changed to check less frequently**?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Also related: [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/switching-from-unlimited-data-plan-to-pay-per-data-what-to-watch-out) and [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5153/is-150-mb-month-enough-for-limited-use).

Comment: @Al Everett Thanks I just found that myself :) voting to close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NetCounter](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.jaqpot.netcounter&feature=search_result) will keep track of data usage. It may not be 100% accurate, but it would be a decent estimate.

Comment: looks perfect by the screen shot - have you used the app before?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, I used it when I first had my Droid phone (a year and a half ago?) but stopped using it since Verizon shows their data usage on their website which is updated about daily.

Answer (score 2):

AT&T has a number u can text to track how much is used. Goto your phone and type *3282# and call like making a phone call and it will send a text message to you showing how much has been used and how much left. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I have to eat my comments on the question.  [ZDBox](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.zdworks.android.toolbox) is yet another app that you can use to track your data usage, and it appears to have some pretty powerful/fantastic additional features.

Answer (score 1):

Install [MyAT&T](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.att.myAttBusiness) app & log into her online wireless account that should be see up on AT&T website. Then check usage from there.

It tells me my phone minutes, text messages & data. I use very little data as I am usually connected to Wi-Fi, but because I am on a limited data plan, this app comes in handy.

Answer (score 0):

Another app which can be used to do this (though it is a paid app) is [SPB Wireless Monitor](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.spb.wirelessmonitor&feature=search_result).