# Traffic for Skype and other apps on Android

Tags: skype, data-monitoring

I've recently bought an HTC Desire and I'm wondering how much traffic some apps generate. I actually want to know two things: how much traffic (estimation, of course) is generated when syncing with gmail/facebook/weather, and how much traffic is generated when I'm online on Skype and when I talk over Skype.

Edit: to clarify, I'm thinking if I should leave some syncing and if I should talk over Skype over 3G, since I have only 1GB per month of traffic.

Comment: See also this previous question http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45/is-there-a-good-app-for-monitoring-the-amount-of-data-traffic

Answer (score 4):

Just download an app from the Market called [PhoneUsage](http://www.appbrain.com/app/phoneusage/com.jupiterapps.phoneusage). It will track how many minutes, text messages, and data you use. You can even view a break down of which apps use how much traffic, and it only tracks over 3G, not WiFi.

Answer (score 4):

The sync traffic for gmail/facebook/weather/... is neglectable (If you have normal text messages with small attachments). 
For Skype **voice** calls, you should estimate 4-7 KiB/s (~ 25 MiB/h).

Users always underestimate the 1GB included traffic. I had the same thought, that it could get tight at the end of the month. But I forgot that:

1. At home and at work my phone uses WLAN and therefore doesn't utilize the data plan
2. 1GB is very much, if you just do some surfing/browsing. (Of course, if you start downloading DVD Images or some kind of torrents, the 1GB will be consumed fast)