# Display data usage by application

Tags: data-monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to monitor the amount of data traffic?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-to-monitor-the-amount-of-data-traffic)

Is there a way I can monitor how much data all the individual apps use? All the traffic monitors I have found only show the total amount.

Comment: That question only asks about total data usage.

Comment: It doesn't state that explicitly anywhere, and several of the answers track per app data usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a program on Google Play called [Network TrafficStats Lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.trafficstats) that does this in most Android versions.  If your phone happens to be compatible to Ice Cream Sandwich, consider upgrading as this feature is built in.